# How can I tell if my ipfs daemon is running the background?

Tags: ipfs

How can I tell if my ipfs daemon is running in the background?

I'm able to execute command like `jsipfs cat <hash>`, but I'm pretty sure my daemon isn't running. I can't seem to find a process named "ipfs" in my process list.

Is there a one-liner command to verify if the ipfs daemon is actually running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commands work offline - `jsipfs cat Qmfoo` will work if you have the whole file in your local repo for example.

If you run a command that requires being online like `jsipfs swarm peers` for example, it'll print a message like `This command must be run in online mode. Try running 'ipfs daemon' first.`

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Is it possible to know which commands run offline? `ipfs add` seems to work fine offline, but that doesn't make sense. How can it upload anything into the network if the daemon isn't running?

Comment: When you run `ipfs add`, you aren't uploading anything to the network, just adding it to your local node. The only thing being offline means is that people can't pull the content from your node.